# Inserting icc color profile into image using Pillow ImageCMS

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, color-profile

I am trying to insert an ICC color profile into an image. Using code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537273/520779) as an example my code looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageCms

# Read image
img = Image.open(IMG_PATH)

# Read profile
profile = ImageCms.getOpenProfile(PROFILE_PATH)

# Save image with profile
img.save(OUT_IMG_PATH, icc_profile=profile)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/----/Documents/code_projects/hfss-misc/icc_profiles/insert_icc_profile_into_image.py", line 17, in <module>
    img.save(OUT_IMG_PATH, icc_profile=srgb_profile)
  File "/home/----/.virtualenvs/color-correction/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2102, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/home/----/.virtualenvs/color-correction/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 706, in _save
    markers.append(icc_profile[:MAX_DATA_BYTES_IN_MARKER])
TypeError: 'PIL._imagingcms.CmsProfile' object is not subscriptable
```

I thought that there might be a problem with my ICC profile so I tried to use one generated by Pillow.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageCms

# Read image
img = Image.open(IMG_PATH)

# Creating sRGB profile
profile = ImageCms.createProfile("sRGB")

# Save image with profile
img.save(OUT_IMG_PATH, icc_profile=profile)
```

I still get the same error, however.

Does anyone know what the cause for this error is?

My system environment is as follows:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 3.6
- Pillow==7.0.0

Comment: You may find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47178272/hue-tint-color-error-converting-tiff-to-jpg-in-python3-with-pillow) helpful

Comment: Thank you for the link @works_as_coded. I am more looking to save the profile with the image without doing the conversion rather than converting the image and saving the converted image.

Comment: This question was asked and answered at https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4464

Answer (score 2):

The answer from github at (https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4464) was to use `profile.to_bytes()`:

```
img.save(OUT_IMG_PATH, icc_profile=profile.tobytes())
```